# Prove that the set of all differentiable real-valued functions $f$ on the interval $(0,3)$ s.t. $f'(2)=b$ is a subspace of $R^{(0,3)}$ iff $b$ = 0

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

My attempt:

Let $S$ $=$ {$f$ | $f$ : $(0,3)$ → $R$, $f'(2) = b$}, and let $W$ $=$ {$f$ | $f$ : $(0,3)$ → $R$}.

Claim: $S$ is a linear subspace of $W$ iff $b=0$

Proof.

I know that $S$
⊆ $W$.
(
⟹
) Suppose S is a subspace of W. Then 
∃
$x$ 
∈
 $(0,3)$ s.t. $f(x)=0$ (the identically zero function). Clearly $f'(2)=0$ ⟹ $b=0$.

(⟸
) Suppose $b=0$. Then $f'(2)=0$, and $f(x)$ $=$ $0$
∈
 $S$. That is, the additive identity is in S. Moreover, S is closed under addition and scalar multiplication because the derivative of a sum of two differentiable functions at $2$ is $0$ and the derivative of a scalar multiple of a differentiable function at $2$ is also $0$. That is, $f'(2)$$+$$g'(2)$ $=$ $0$ and $af'(2)=0$ for $f$,$g$ 
∈
 $S$, and $a$
∈
$R$. Thus S satisfies the three conditions of a subspace.

Therefore, $S$ is a linear subspace of $W$ iff $b=0$ as claimed.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is not completely correct, and it could be written much more clearly.  In the first part you establish that if $S$ is a linear space, then $b=0.$  The beginning of the second part where you assume $b\neq0$ is unnecessary.  The first part is equivalent to the statement that if $b\neq0$ then $S$ is not a linear subspace.

In the second part, where you say, "Thus if $b=0\implies S$ is a linear subspace of $W$," it makes it sound as if this follows from what has come before, but it does not.  It follows from what comes later, after "This is because,...", or it would, if the word "constant" were changed to "differentiable" wherever it appears.  That $f'(2)=0$ does not mean that $f$ is constant.

Comment: Does this work for the second part: Suppose b is not zero. Then f'(2) does not equal 0, which implies that the additive identity is not in S. Hence S is not a linear subspace of W. Therefore, S is a linear subspace of W iff b=0.

Comment: @Karam No, you have already shown that if $S$ is a linear subspace then $b=0$  This is the same as showing that if $b\neq0$ then $S$ is not a linear subspace.  What you need to show though, is that if $b=0$ then $S$ is a linear space.  That is, if $b=0$, then $S$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

Comment: Got it. That makes much more sense now. I've edited my post.

Comment: please check now. Thanks.